# State matrix norm (respect to Matrix) with matrix norm (respect to infinity)

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-calculus

$$
\begin{array}{l}{\text { We have following matrix }} \\ {\qquad T=\left(\begin{array}{cc}{-3} & {1} \\ {1} & {2}\end{array}\right)} \\ {\text { a) Show that, with }\|x\|_{T}=\|T x\|_{\infty} \text { a vector norm is  defined for } \mathbb{R}^{2} \text { }} \\ {\text { (Hint: Properties of a norm.) }}\end{array}
$$
$$
\begin{array}{l}{\text { b) Sketch the unit circle } B_{T}=\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{2}\|x\|_{T} \leq 1\right\}} \\ {\text { c) State the }\|\cdot\| T \text { assigned matrix norm }} \\ {\quad\|A\|_{T}:=\max _{x \neq 0} \frac{\|A x\|_{T}}{\|x\|_{T}}} \\ {\text { with the matrix norm}\|\cdot\|_{\infty} \text { }}\end{array}
$$

Trying to do c) my hint is to reform it until there is only a maxx norm but how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint.* Try to rewrite $\max_{x\ne0}\frac{\|Ax\|_T}{\|x\|_T}$ in the form of $\max_{y\ne0}\frac{\|By\|_\infty}{\|y\|_\infty}$ where $B$ is some matrix that depends on $T$ and $A$, and $y$ is some vector depending on $T$ and $x$. It follows that $\|A\|_T=\|B\|_\infty$.

Full solution:

> ! For every nonzero vector $x$, let $y=Tx$. Then 
>   $$
> \frac{\|Ax\|_T}{\|x\|_T}
> =\frac{\|TAx\|_\infty}{\|Tx\|_\infty}
> =\frac{\|TAT^{-1}y\|_\infty}{\|y\|_\infty}.\tag{1}
> $$
>   Since $T$ is invertible, there is a one-to-one correspondence between $x$ and $y$. Therefore, the maximum of the LHS of $(1)$ over all nonzero vectors $x$ is equal to the maximum of the RHS over all nonzero vectors $y$. It follows that
>   $$
> \|A\|_T=\max_{x\ne0}\frac{\|Ax\|_T}{\|x\|_T}
> =\max_{y\ne0}\frac{\|TAT^{-1}y\|_\infty}{\|y\|_\infty}
> =\|TAT^{-1}\|_\infty.
> $$

Comment: $$
\|\mathbf{x}\|_{T} = 
\|T x\|_{\infty}
$$ but what's with the $$
\|A x\|_{T}
$$

Comment: So i just have to say C is random? and has to be = By?

Comment: is there a method to find vectors or matrices that depend on 2 factos like a matrix and a vector or 2 matrices? Basis change?

Comment: Yeah i'm not that good in math trying to get better $$\mid \mid Ax \mid \mid_{T} = \mid \mid TAx \mid \mid_{inf} $$ is there any good site/video to get better with that norm formulations and equations?  Are these equations always valid?

Comment: Now i basically have $$ \frac{ \mid \mid TAx \mid \mid_{inf}}{\mid \mid Tx \mid \mid_{inf}} $$ My problem now is to get that B if i use y = Tx  I guess i got it $$By=TAx$$ $$y=Tx$$ $$BTx = TAx$$ $$BT=TA$$ $$B=TAT^{-1}$$ ??

Comment: $$ x=T^{-1}y$$ is that x in terms of y

Comment: @comrade Yes. Congrats, you are now done.

Comment: Thanks! Very good help!